# Filter elements having same value at the corresponding index of two lists

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have 2 lists, and I want to match each item with related index. what is the formula ? I have used set but it does not consider specific index.

```
list1 = [1 , 2 , 3, 5, 8]
list2 = [2 , 2 , 8, 5, 1]

out_put= [2 , 5]
```

Comment: @JimFasarakisHilliard I do not think it is a right dupe target as this question is related to common elements between the two lists at the same index (unlike finding the intersection of two list). I am not reopening the question, in case I missed anything and you might be able to clarify me

Comment: @MoinuddinQuadri the answer you gave (`[i for i, j in zip(list1, list2) if i==j]`) is nearly exactly the same as the code in the top answer from the dupe (`[i for i, j in zip(a, b) if i == j]`). So I would argue that this is an accurate dupe target.

Comment: @JGreenwell Yeah. I saw that. I am not sure why someone wrote this answer in that question :/ Because again that answer was irrelevant there.

Comment: My assumption is it was so we could have one dupe target for both cases @MoinuddinQuadri and then people could find the version they needed through the linked duplicates.

Answer (score 4):

You may use [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) to filter the same elements at each index of both the lists as:

```
>>> list1 = [1 , 2 , 3, 5, 8]
>>> list2 = [2 , 2 , 8, 5, 1]
>>> [i for i, j in zip(list1, list2) if i==j]
[2, 5]
```

Comment: Oh boy , you beat me in 20 sec.

Comment: @Arman god you guys are fast... couldn't blink an eye and already answered...

Answer (score 1):

using [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) function:

```
res = [x[0] for x in zip(list1, list2) if x[0] == x[1]] # [2, 5]
```